# Change user password on the front end

Tags: ajax, user-profile, password

I'm building a profile page for members on a site where members can change their password. I'm sending the request with ajax, and can successfully change password if I have the input name "password" correct with the users current password.

My problem is that I get a success-response, when I should have gotten an error-response. (Password isn't changed, but I have no way of telling the user there was en error).

My JS is something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "",
    data: dataString,
    success: function(data) {
        console.log("Password successfully changed");
    },
    error: function(data) {
        console.log("Error. Password did not change");
    }
});
```

Comment: Haven't actually tested anything yet, but it looks like it should return errors if there is any problems. Have you had a look at UsersController@actionSaveUser?

Comment: Just to clarify: You say "and can successfully change password if I have the input name". That means it works, given that the right password is entered, right? In the second paragraph, do you mean you get an success-response, even if there is an error? See anything in the log?

Comment: @FredCarlsen Correct. It works if the given password is entered. So far, so good. My problem is I don't get error-response. I can't see anything in the log.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently the users/saveUser (and the deprecated users/setPassword) controller action doesn’t support Ajax requests, so there won’t really be an easy way to tell if it worked or not.

If you really want to update user passwords over Ajax, your best bet will be to write a plugin with its own custom controller action, which mimics the password-related stuff in [UsersController::actionSaveUser()](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/controllers/UsersController#actionSaveUser-detail), but probably calls [UsersService::changePassword()](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/services/UsersService#changePassword-detail) rather than [saveUser()](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/services/UsersService#saveUser-detail) since you only care about updating the password. And have that controller respond with JSON if it’s an Ajax request, rather than assuming it’s not.

Take a look at [EntriesController::actionSaveEntry()](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/controllers/EntriesController#actionSaveEntry-detail) for an example of a controller action that *does* support Ajax.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the answer. I don't have to use ajax, think I'll stick to regular post.